# struts 2 url dispatcher forward

Tags: struts2

Hi i am facing a problem with struts2 when using the following code in web.xml

```
       <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>        
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

when i configured like above all my jstl tags in all jsp were not working
but when i remove

```
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

from the above configuration they are working

but i requried  `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` 
  for url rewriting

Can any one suggest me what i have to do to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

instead of `FilterDispatcher`, that is deprecated. More info [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3742).